Net torque on a rotating pulley
Suppose a pulley is wounded with a rope and a force of $25 \,\text{N}$ is applied along that rope. If we want to find the total torque on the pulley about its center which is fixed, we multiply the force by the radius of the pulley. But why don't we take in account all the forces acting on the pulley by the wounded part of the rope, won't every tiny (curved) bit of the rope apply a force of $25 \,\text{N}$ in a direction perpendicular to the radius of the pulley?


The point of contact of the rope and the pulley, where you have written "25N" is actually NOT the true point where the force and torque are applied.  In reality there is EITHER a dependence on friction, as you imply in your drawing OR if frictionless then the rope is glued at a particular point, and the force and torque is applied at that point only.
In the case of the frictional contact assumption, it is actually the little segments of contact force that sum up to provide the 25N torque. As you move along the rope away from the mass, the tension declines in each segment according to an approximate formula known as the "capstan equation."  Depending on the problem statement, sometimes you are supposed to use this formula, and sometimes you just assume constant tension.  You have to infer the approach from context I guess.
Interestingly, the capstan equation provides some insight into why it's possible to fairly high holding torque with just a few turns of rope.  See this wiki page for more.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capstan_equation

Is it correct that if we take the wounded part + pulley to be a single system then we can say that the applied 25 N will only be responsible for producing torue? (String is massless)

Yes, that is the usual and probably the simplest approach.  In that case all your small force segments will be internal and not contribute.  Only the 25N force will be external.

OH actually there will be a reaction force from the pulley supoprt that is also "external."  But it was too late to edit the above comment and anyway, I think that is understood from context.

The main reason is that the only cause that"every minute part" of the rope which is applying a force is due to the force which pulls the rope from its end. Like a hand pulling it or the mass, in your case. It will apply no extra force on pulley and so the total force on the pulley is  only $25N$
Hence, the formula is used in that way.
$$\vec{\tau} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$$
I hope you understand!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

For simplicity, assume that the rope is massless and consists of many small identical segments. Consider two consecutive segments of the rope. By Newton's third law, the force applied by the first segment on the second is equal and opposite to the force applied by the second segment on the first. So every segment of the rope except the ends is pulled both forward by the segment ahead and backward by the segment behind it. This force is the tension. Since the rope is massless, the net force on each segment is zero and we have, for segment $n$,
$$T_n - T_{n+1} = F_n$$
where $T$ is the tension and $F$ is the force applied by the segment on the pulley.
If there is no friction, the tension is constant throughout the rope. Each segment applies no force to the pulley, with the exception of the last which applies the full $25 \,\text{N}$ through the point of attachment. If there is friction, then each segment applies some force (and therefore torque) to the pulley. The tension in the subsequent segment is decreased by exactly this amount as seen in the equation. This continues until the last segment is reached which applies the remainder of the force through the point of attachment.
So, in any case, it is definitely not true that every segment individually applies the full $25 \,\text{N}$ of force to the pulley. By applying the equation, we see that the sum (in the infinitesimal limit, an integral) of all the forces on the pulley, $\sum F_n$, equals $T_1$ which is $25 \,\text{N}$ by hypothesis. Therefore, the force is only applied once.
